# How to set scrollbars to only part of the modal?

Tags: html, css

I have a modal with some input elements and buttons at the top and bottom and have grid in the middle of the modal. And the grid's height is lets say `400px` (before expanding the contents of the grid). If I expand the grid that content will go beyond `400px`. So I want to add a scrollbar to it so that only when it exceeds `400px`, it should have vertical scrollbar. But I want elements at the top of the modal(buttons and other elements) still visible while I scroll the grid. How can I apply it.

This is what I tried:

```css
.table1 {
  height: 400px;
}

.table2 {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<table class="table1">
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
</table>

<table class="table1">
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

So, in this scenario I have more elements in the table2 which exceeds its set height. So I want to apply scrollbar when it exceeds 400px. But when I do that it is overlapping with the table1. I want to avoid it.I want table2 to have scrolling in its position.

Comment: CSS alone is mostly useless, without seeing the HTML it is supposed to apply to, it tells us almost nothing. Provide a proper [mre] of your issue.

Comment: Hi @CBroe, I have edited the description.

Answer (score 0):

Change the grid's height to use max-height instead. It's probably worth setting a min-height as well so the content doesn't collapse. It's normal practice to only set the vertical overflow to scroll if you don't want any horizontal scrolling as well.

```
.middle{
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a combo of `max-height: 400px;` and `overflow-y: scroll;` on a wrapper div, you can achieve that.

See here:

```js
const table = document.getElementById("table1");

function extendTable() {
  var row = table.insertRow();
  row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = "NEW";
  row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = "NEW";
  row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = "NEW";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey
}

.modal {
  max-width: 30rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px
}

.scroll-wrapper {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="modal">

    <button onClick="extendTable()">Click to extend</button>

    <div class="scroll-wrapper">
      <table id="table1">
        <th>Column1</th>
        <th>Column2</th>
        <th>Column3</th>

        <tr>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    More info at the bottom of the table

  </div>
</body>
```